# Atlassian Bamboo: First plan with a simple job of downloading a local git repo

Tags: bamboo

I just downloaded the free trial of Bamboo continuous integration server, and created the first plan with nothing but downloading the source code from the git. I have a local git repository on the bamboo machine so the git URL is pointing to a local path.

The problem is that when I run the job, it never finishes even after waiting for an hour. This is the last lines of the activity log:

```
07-Apr-2011 20:03:23    Checking out revision f9dc82500914333ed4bbdae5ed038771fd658c3c. 
07-Apr-2011 20:03:23    Creating local git repository in '/home/bob/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/DEV-DEV-1/.git'.
```

From the shell I can go to the directory shown in the log and see that the source code were cloned correctly to the bamboo working directory. But the job will never finish and the log will not have any more update from here. I have to manually terminate the job. Any ideas? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, since the Bamboo instance we have at work pulls from Accurev and not Git, and I've never run into this problem myself - but it may be hung **because** there isn't a builder defined for that plan. You might try defining a builder (even if it's one that you know will fail) just to see if it makes it to that next step.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem.
It's not very original solution but I just uninstalled bamboo and installed it again.. Now it works now